# Need for examples in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

For me, measure theory is a part of mathematics dealing with Lebesgue integrals and so on.

1. So, professor told us that there are functions differentiable on $(a,b)$ but whose derivative is not Lebesgue integrable over any $[a_1,b_1] \subset (a,b)$. If someone could provide example it would be great.
2. If we have a function $f$ that is absolutely continuous, then it is a standard result that it is almost everywhere differentiable, and that its derivative is integrable. It could be showed by example that if function is only differentiable almost everywhere, its derivative does not need to be integrable at all(I seeked reference for this in 1.) ,so reference I seek now can we somehow have greater class of functions then the absolutely continous ones, such that they are differentiable almost everywhere and the derivative is integrable?
3. If we have a differentiable function $f$ on $(a,b)$ , then it has to be some segment $[a_1,b_1]\subset (a,b)$ such that $f'$ on $[a_1,b_1]$ is Riemann integrable. Does this have to hold? If it does not, please give me a counter-example. For those wandering around, thinking those questions are trivial, just to remind that in order that Lebesgue integral exists, you need ABSOLUTE INTEGRABILITY so negative answer on this one does imply the negative on the first one.

   Thanks for your answers, hints and reference!

Comment: The counterexample to (1) will also be a counterexample to (3): the derivative $f'$ will be unbounded on every interval, and an unbounded function is never Riemann integrable.

Comment: For (2), the Cantor function is such an example: it is differentiable almost everywhere and the derivative is 0 where it exists.  But this class of functions would not be very interesting.  What's interesting about the absolutely continuous functions is not only that the derivative exists a.e. and is integrable, but that its integral actually equals the function.  I can't think of any useful property that your class of functions would have.

Comment: Nate, can you just put your thoughts, along with all reference, in an answer, you will get a +15 rep, which is here like dollars/euros in the r/l

Comment: @NateEldredge: I assume the OP is just exploring the real analysis jungle?

Comment: For 100k points you can have a T-shirt :-). Unfortunately mine ripped after two days wear.

Comment: Well, I don't want to post an answer until I can actually answer the questions!  I did find https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478974/a-pathological-example-of-a-differentiable-function-whose-derivative-is-not-inte which similarly asks for a function whose derivative is nowhere integrable, but it doesn't have a complete answer.

Comment: @copper.hat yes, my professor is exploring with us analysis jungle.

Comment: @copper.hat I already got the T-shirt, back when it only took a few thousand points :-)

Comment: @copper.hat, wait they give you in r/l the T-shirt because you have 100k rep?? That is about the most awesome thing I have heard in a month. Thanks, you made my day.

Comment: And a mug (though they only had SE ones left for me) and gobs of stickers. I was a little disappointed at the T-shirt quality, but I think my teenagers are secretly relieved. (In fact, perhaps they ripped it, never thought of that possibility!) Then again, you get what you pay for :-). Actually, I would not mind paying for a higher quality shirt...

Comment: @copper.hat getting 100K rep means that you know a lot of mathematics, you are interested in a lot of mathematics that also interests other people and you are here at least 3 hours everyday, this is in fact by far the hardest MMO I played in my life, and the most addictive one(there is no cure).... That does not mean any paying...

Comment: @nikola: I am no mathematician, unfortunately. I have made most mistakes that can be made, so am happy if I can point out the potholes to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 3) there are examples of differentiable functions with bounded derivative whose derivative is not Riemann integrable in any interval. 
The reference is a paper of Y. Katznelson and K. Stromberg. "Everywhere differentiable, nowhere monotone, functions, Am. Math. Monthly, 81 (4), (1974), 349-353. See also the link [nowhere monotone](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167323/everywhere-differentiable-function-that-is-nowhere-monotonic) for more references.

Concerning 1) I only have a partial answer. A differentiable function sends sets of measure zero into sets of measure zero. If its derivative is Lebesgue integrable on an interval, then the function is absolutely continuous in that interval. 
In the paper Sebastian Lindner  Additional properties of the measure $v_f$ Tatra Mountains Mathematical Publications. Volume 28, 2004, No. 2: 199-205.[Lindner](https://www.sav.sk/index.php?lang=en&doc=journal-list&part=list_articles&journal_issue_no=1135#abstract_768) in the Example 5 Lindner constructs a function which sends sets of measure zero into sets of measure zero but whose variation is infinite in any interval. It is not exactly (1) but it is very much in the same direction. Instead of using broken lines in his construction, one could try to use more regular functions to get differentiability.